# Campos dinâmicos para Controller - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

Tenho este `JavaScript` que cria novos campos para mim quando preciso e que faz a chamada para criar o `JSON`.

Este contador dentro da função `adicionarCampos()` é necessário para outra coisa independente do que preciso, mesmo porque ele não é sequencial como escrevi abaixo:

```js
function adicionarCampos(contador, botao) {

  var html = "Origem: <input type='number' name='Origem[" + contador + "]' />";
  html += "Destino: <input type='number' name='Destino[" + contador + "]' />";

  contador++;

  // Remove onclick 
  // Add onclick adicionarCampos(contador,$(this))
}

function formToJson(form) {
  var formArray = ($('#' + form).serializeArray())
  var returnArray = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; i++) {
    returnArray[formArray[i]['name']] = formArray[i]['value'];
  }

  alert(returnArray);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Cadastrar",
    dataType: "json",
    data: returnArray,
    success: function(data) {}
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <div id="camposNovos">

    // Estes novos campos virão aqui

  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="formToJson(form)"> Cadastrar </button>
</form>
```

Meu Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Cadastrar(....)
{}
```

O que eu passo dentro do `Cadastrar()`?
Eu já tentei `string returnArray`, `object returnArray`, `string[] returnArray`, `object[] returnArray`, todos me trazem `null`.

Há outra maneira mais simples de passar essas informações do meu formulário para `JSON` e depois para o `controller`?

Tenho um objeto também:

```
public class JsonToObject
{
    public int Origem { get; set; }
    public int Destino { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não recomendaria você nomear os seus inputs com o índice junto, particularmente eu utilizaria o atributo `data-contador` para isso... mas seguindo o seu código, poderia resolver da seguinte forma.

```js
function adicionarCampos(contador, botao) {

  var html = "Origem: <input type='number' name='Origem[" + contador + "]' />";
  html += "Destino: <input type='number' name='Destino[" + contador + "]' />";

  contador++;

  // Remove onclick 
  // Add onclick adicionarCampos(contador,$(this))
}

function formToJson(form) {
  var formArray = ($('#' + form).serializeArray())
  var returnArray = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; i++) {
    returnArray[i] = { 
      Origem : $("input[name='Origem["+i+"]']").val(),
     Destino : $("input[name='Destino["+i+"]']").val()
    };
      
  }

  console.log(returnArray);
  
  //post comentado apenas para exibir o resultado no console
  /*
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Cadastrar",
    dataType: "json",
    data: returnArray,
    success: function(data) {}
  });*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <div id="camposNovos">
    <!-- Exemplo de campos -->    
    Origem: <input type="number" name="Origem[0]" />    
    Destino: <input type="number" name="Destino[0]" />
    <br/>
    Origem: <input type="number" name="Origem[1]" />
    Destino: <input type="number" name="Destino[1]" />
    <br/>
    Origem: <input type="number" name="Origem[2]" />
    Destino:  <input type="number" name="Destino[2]" />
  </div>
  <br/>
  <button type="button" onclick="formToJson('form')"> Cadastrar </button>
</form>
```

Já na sua controller você pode receber essa coleção da seguinte forma

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Cadastrar(List<JsonToObject> model)
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Caso esteja usando uma model pode fazer algo assim:

```
<button type="button" onclick="formToJson('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))')"> Cadastrar </button>
```

Ou tente alterar sua função "formToJson" e verifique se assim funciona:

```
function formToJson(form) {
  var formArray = JSON.stringify(jQuery('#' + form).serializeArray());
  var returnArray = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; i++) {
    returnArray[formArray[i]['name']] = formArray[i]['value'];
  }

  alert(returnArray);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Cadastrar",
    dataType: "json",
    data: returnArray,
    success: function(data) {}
  });
}
```